# 「一週間後に解約する」 but 「一週間後での解約」, why not the same particle?

Tags: particle-に, particle-の, particle-で

Some rough Google search shows:

> 一週間後に解約する (✓)
>
> 一週間後で解約する (☓)

but:

> 一週間後にの解約 (☓)
>
> 一週間後での解約 (✓)

If that's right, why is that discrepancy?

Questions below seem related:

[What's the difference between に and で when speaking of time of an action?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/685/whats-the-difference-between-%E3%81%AB-and-%E3%81%A7-when-speaking-of-time-of-an-action)

[に vs で again: 前に vs 後で](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2201/%E3%81%AB-vs-%E3%81%A7-again-%E5%89%8D%E3%81%AB-vs-%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%A7)

---

**和訳**

少しググった限りでは、

> 一週間後に解約する (◯)
>
> 一週間後で解約する (☓)

に対し、

> 一週間後にの解約 (☓)
>
> 一週間後での解約 (◯)

なようですが、誤りでなければ、なぜこういうふうに食い違っているのですか？

以下の質問とも関係がありそうです。

[What's the difference between に and で when speaking of time of an action?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/685/whats-the-difference-between-%E3%81%AB-and-%E3%81%A7-when-speaking-of-time-of-an-action)

[に vs で again: 前に vs 後で](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2201/%E3%81%AB-vs-%E3%81%A7-again-%E5%89%8D%E3%81%AB-vs-%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%A7)

Comment: I am sorry I completely drop my claim. l'électeur's answer is correct. Source : http://www.japanese-edu.org.hk/sympo/upload/manuscript/20121016011038.pdf#search=%27%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE+%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E%27

Answer (score 3):

***Taking Actions at Specific Times:***

Plain and simple, what governs the particle choice for expressing the time of action is the ***part of speech*** that follows the particle -- nothing else.

> Use **に** with verbs:

「[一週間後]{いっしゅうかんご}**に**[解約]{かいやく}する」 = "to cancel after a week"

「5[月]{がつ}**に**[渡米]{とべい}します。」 = "I am going to the U.S. in May."

「2[年前]{ねんまえ}**に**[結婚]{けっこん}しました。」 = "I got married 2 years ago."

> Use **の** or **での** with nouns:

「一週間後**での**（or just **の**）解約」 = "a/the cancellation after a week"

「5月**の**渡米」 = "a/the/one's visit to the U.S. in May"

「2年前**の**結婚」 = "one's marriage 2 years ago"

> Exceptions:

Certain time words ***do not*** take a particle when followed by a verb or verb phrase, but even with those, you need to place a 「の」 when followed by a noun.

Those words include: [来週]{らいしゅう}、[先週]{せんしゅう}、[来年]{らいねん}, etc.  = next week, last week, next year, etc.

Correct: 「来年[行]{い}きます。」 = "I will go next year."

Incorrect: 「来年に行きます。」

Correct: 「先週の[旅行]{りょこう}」 = "one's trip last week"

**Finally, regarding combining particles:**

「にの」 is just not a possible particle combination at least in standard Japanese.

Possible combinations include: での、への、へも、とも、のも、でも、にも, etc.

I will not give examples here as it would be off-topic.  If asked as a separate question, I might post an answer.   Just mentioned it because you used 「にの」 in  「一週間後にの解約」, which is an incorrect phrase.

Comment: How about 「食事の後｛あと｝でゆっくりする」?  The part of speech following is a verb, but 「で」 sounds fine?

Comment: Yes, it does. Because you are specifying certain time, 食事の後, after eating. http://www.ise.chuo-u.ac.jp/ISE/outline/Gmajor/nihongo/26.html

Comment: I might rather say "certain POINT of time". Because で does not include the continuation. Ex:食事の後で,（time), 東京駅で（location), 車で（the method), etc etc.