# How 二週間 can be used to say "In two weeks..."

Tags: particles, time

How can one use 二週間 to say, "In two weeks from today, I am going to Tokyo."

I am confused on how one would use particles here and I need some help.

Comment: You may also want to look at http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21653/%E4%B8%80%E9%80%B1%E9%96%93%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%AB%E8%A7%A3%E7%B4%84%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-but-%E4%B8%80%E9%80%B1%E9%96%93%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E8%A7%A3%E7%B4%84-why-not-the-same-particle

Answer (score 4):

If it were me, I would say

> 今日から二週間後[に]、東京へ行く。

I don't think 後 is usually considered a particle (助詞).

二週間 = a *duration* of two weeks. So you need to express after that duration has passed.

Answer (score 2):

Two other ways to say this:

> 二週間したら東京へ行く。
>
> 二週間[経]{た}ったら東京へ行く。

The verb する in the first one is roughly equivalent to the verb 経つ in the second one, and both mean "to pass time".