# Difference between バスに and バスでスマホを忘れてしまいました

Tags: word-choice, particle-に, particle-で

What is the difference between

> バス**で**スマホを忘れてしまいました

and

> バス**に**スマホを忘れてしまいました?

I vaguely remember there being a nuance difference between these two sentences but I forgot what it was... Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between に and で when speaking of time of an action?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/685/whats-the-difference-between-%e3%81%ab-and-%e3%81%a7-when-speaking-of-time-of-an-action)

Comment: It is certainly a good answer and I learned from it but I feel like something is still missing? I also lack the brains to apply the explanation there to this sentence

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/105/9831 `で is where an action is performed and に is the "direction" toward/to/into which the result of an action happens.`

Answer (score 2):

While I think the distinction between `で` and `に` in the general sense has been addressed in other questions, I don't think there's any harm in explaining how it works for `忘れる` specifically.

> バス**で**スマホを忘れてしまいました

"I forgot my phone on the bus". The `で` here is emphasizing that the action of forgetting your phone happened on the bus.

> バス**に**スマホを忘れてしまいました

"I left my phone in the bus". The `に` here is emphasizing that the bus is the place where the action - forgetting your phone - was directed. You forgot something into the bus, if you will, and consequently that's presumably where it still is (unless someone moved it).

To really drive this home, let's look at one more sentence:

> バスで席の下にスマホを忘れてしまいました

"I left my phone under my seat on the bus". This sentence is talking about performing the action of leaving your phone under your seat, and that action was performed on the bus. This might be an unnatural level of specificity, but hopefully it drives home the difference between particles.

Anecdotally, I see `忘れる` used primarily with `で`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer since this seems to be a possible duplicate...

バスで忘れた focuses on where you did the forgetting (action).

バスに忘れた focuses on where the item was forgotten (location).

'On the bus, I forgot my phone.' vs. 'I forgot (lost) my phone inside the bus.'.