# ここ10年でずいぶん's meaning

Tags: particle-で

コンピューターの技術は、ここ10年でずいぶんです。

What does ここ10年でずいぶんです mean.

ずいぶん means remarkable (I searched from a website),but I don't know what で functions and what ここ10年 means.

In my opinion, I think it means "Computer technology will be remarkable in this 10 years"

Comment: This appears to be a broken sentence although the meaning is guessable. Is this from a credible source, and did you copy it correctly? Do you have any problem understanding it if it were ずいぶん進歩しています?

Comment: I'm sorry. I accidentally dropped で from this sentence. The correct one is 
コンピューターの技術は、ここ10年でずいぶん. It is from my university homework. ずいぶん進歩してます I think it means extremely developed ?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but ここ10年でずいぶんです is still strange. Is there really nothing between ずいぶん and です?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I misread it again. The full sentence is コンピューターの技術は、ここ10年でずいぶん_____ ( here is a verb 進む to be filled). Ok. The real point is I don't understand what で functions here and what ここ10年 means. I think ここ10年 means from this year to next 10 years. (within this 10 years) Am I correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the comment, the correct sentence is:

> コンピューターの技術は、**ここ10年で**ずいぶん**進んでいます**。
>   The computer technology **has advanced** greatly **in the last 10 years**.

Or:

> コンピューターの技術は、**ここ10年で**ずいぶん**進みました**。
>   The computer technology **advanced** greatly **in the last 10 years**.

`ここ + time-length` is a way to say "last ～". For example ここ3日で is "in the last three days". To say "next ～", you can use この先. For example この先3日で means "in the next three days". This particle で is a equivalent of English "in" used with a time frame.

This means the sentence is about the **past** 10 years, so you have to conjugate 進む ("to advance") into either the -teiru form or the past (-ta) form.

Comment: Excuse me, Can I ask something else ? This sentence　この10年間にどんなことが変わりましたか？ What does this mean ?  Is この + amount of time same with "ここ + time-length"(meaning last ～ ) And why に is used here instead of で(time frame) ?

Comment: @Kiw "What has changed in the last 10 years?" I can at least say この10年に and この10年で are interchangeable in this sentence, but it's hard for me to logically explain why. There are many questions regarding で/に for time, such as https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/685/5010 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16269/5010