# About phrases like 売れに売れる

Tags: clause-pattern

売れに売れる seems to be a relatively common phrase used to describe something that sold very well.

I am wondering whether one can substitute other verbs in this phrase or if it is only used with 売れる.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62682/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5455/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1856/9831

Comment: Thanks for the references!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some other verbs are possible, but probably まくる is more versatile.

- その日は飲みに飲んだ

  I drank a lot that day.
- 東京五輪はもめにもめた

  There were a lot of disagreements in Tokyo Olympics.

The construction implies a sort of excess.

**Examples where this construction is not possible:**

- I read a lot of manga

  ?漫画を読みに読んだ.

  漫画を読みまくった is more natural.
- I watched a lot of films

  *私は映画を見に見た

  私は映画を見まくった is the only option.

Comment: Thank you for bringing up まくる. Do you think there is a difference in meaning between the VにV structure and Vまくる that could explain why we can use both in certain cases or only one of them in others?

Comment: As for meaning, VにV  sounds somewhat 'V happens to the limit'. So 飲みに飲んだ sounds more like 'I drank to the point I lost my memory' while 飲みまくった more like just 'drank a lot'. But the difference is small.  In terms of register, my feeling is that まくる is more vulgar.