# Interrogatives + じょし

Tags: grammar

In cases like 何でも and 何も, are they considered words on their own, or are they considered words + じょし? I've been told that it's one word, but sometimes the particle is separated like in: どこへもいきません。If it is a word plus a particle, why are the particles でも, か, and も used, what do they mean, and how do they change the interrogative? Also, how would I say "I want to go everywhere" in Japanese? I was told that どこも行きたい is incorrect, but I don't know how else to phrase it. Doesn't どこも mean "nowhere" when the verb is negative, and "everywhere" when the verb is positive?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, monolingual dictionaries consider 何でも, 誰でも, いつでも, どこでも and such as two words, i.e., an interrogative 何/etc followed by the particle でも. (They have an entry for 何でも anyway because 何でも has a significant meaning as a set phrase.) 誰にも, どこからでも and so on are three words (だれ + に + も = "to anyone", どこ + から + でも = "from anywhere").

Dictionaries for Japanese learners may list them as one word for the sake of convenience. There is [more than one way to separate words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36310/5010), after all.

"I want to go everywhere" is どこ**へでも**行きたい or どこ**にでも**行きたい. You need a destination marker へ or に. You have to use でも instead of も if your sentence is non-negative. For details, see: [「どこでもある」と「どこにもある」の使い分け](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17697/5010)