# Using で to mark location with ある?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-で

My understanding is that the verb ある describes where something **is**, which means に is the correct particle to mark location. However there have been several cases I've come across where ある's location actually uses で:

> (Requesting vacation time from a boss) あの、実は来月、私の国**で**姉の結婚式がありまして...

> 日本**で**はよくある - be common in Japan

I know I've seen more, but I'm struggling to find more at the moment. If more examples would help let me know.

Is this related to how we mark location with で [in noun/adjective sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21496/4382) somehow?

Comment: Related or dup [Why is it である not にある in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14259/45489)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ある usually describes a (long-term) existence, but ある sometimes means "(for an event) to happen; to be held". In such cases, you have to use not に but で just like other action verbs. よく ("commonly", "often") is an adverb that clearly indicates the following ある means "to happen".

Examples (use of に is incorrect):

- 明日デパート**で**セールがある。
  There will be a sale at the department store tomorrow.
- この企画について昨日の会議**で**決定があった。
  A decision about this project was made at yesterday's meeting.

See also:

- [Why not 東京で?「東京にいつ激しい地震があるか誰にもわからない」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94014/5010)