# Why de is used in second sentence?

Tags: particle-に, particle-で

I am currently studying Minna no nihongo. I came across these two sentences [image]

Why was de used in gakkodewa , instead of gakkoniwa in second sentence?

Comment: Here, に marks the location of existence, and で marks the location of action. This answer will be of help:  http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60/particles-%E3%81%AB-vs-%E3%81%A7/4594#4594

Comment: @chocolate Thank you for helping. I got it now. 

Comment: Because います takes に、 習う and most other verbs take で

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these two examples, there are two main differences you should learn.

**に** in the first sentence is used to explain the location that something or someone exists.

**で** in the second sentence is used to explain the location that an action takes places.