# What does '家に、とてもおしゃべりですが、学校に、ぜんぜん話しません' translate to?

Tags: translation, に-and-で

I'm trying to translate the sentence 'at home, she's very talkative but at school, she never talks/is very shy' roughly into Japanese. Does '家に、とてもおしゃべりですが、学校に、ぜんぜん話しません' make sense? If not, how should I reword it?

Answer (score 3):

- As a place marker, you have to use で instead of these two に. に is used with motion verbs (such as 行く, 来る, 動く) and verbs that describes existence (such as いる, ある, 住む). See: [Particles: に vs. で](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60/5010)
- This is a typical case where [contrastive-*wa*](https://jlptbootcamp.com/2012/02/japanese-particles-the-contrastive-wa/) has to be used.
- I think there are a bit too many commas, although this is a minor problem.

Corrected version:

> （彼女は）家**では**とてもおしゃべりですが、学校**では**ぜんぜん話しません。