# Particle Use When Using Form V-ている/ある at a Location: で or に?

Tags: particles

So imagine I get asked this question, perhaps when calling someone:
図書館...何をしている。
Perhaps I am reading a book, so:
［僕は］としょかん...本を読んでいる。
Here is the problem. For "...", I am conflicted on whether to use で or に in each instance and in general. I know that being at a location is に, and doing an action at a location is で, but what of this sentence pattern? Are there specific cases for whether to use one or the other?

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about some action that is taking place in the 図書館, so you have to use で.

> 図書館**で**本を読んでいます。

- [Particles: に vs. で](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60/5010)

There is a subsidiary verb いる used to express progressive "-ing", but it doesn't interfere with this rule.

Comment: Thank you, but how come the exception "placeに勤めています"?

Comment: ^ It should be more like 「companyに勤めています」"work for a company", 「placeで働いています」"work in a place", no? eg 「運送会社に勤めています」「大阪で働いています」

Comment: @BigRigz The particle に is both 1) a location marker used with existence verbs like ある, and 2) a destination marker. ～に勤めています is used in the latter meaning.

Comment: Okay, thank you both.

Comment: Wait, sorry. @naruto, what do you mean by "destination marker"?

Comment: @BigRigz It's に as in 学校に行く ("go *to* school") or アメリカに旅行する ("travel *to* America"). There is no "movement" involved in 本を読む, so no に is required.

Comment: Alright, thank you.