# The difference between 学校に勉強します and 学校で勉強します

Tags: nuances, particles

I'm trying to understand the difference between に and で as particles in the following example:
学校に勉強します。
学校で勉強します。
What are the nuances between these two expressions? Any help or explanation is very appreciated.

Comment: Where did you see the sentence 学校に勉強します?

Comment: Just wanted to mention that "I'm studying **to** school" doesn't make any sense in English either, it must be "I'm studying **at** school"

Comment: @Leebo I didn't actually see the sentence, I just assumed it is correct because　に is sometimes translated to 'at' in Japanese. For example, ケーキが冷蔵庫にある。I didn't realise that に can only be used with a select number of verbs like ある、いる、すむ.

Comment: I see, no problem. The reason I ask is because it helps the answerers know what the state of your knowledge is. More information about why the question is being asked helps out.

Answer (score 2):

学校で勉強します is the only correct sentence. 学校に勉強します is ungrammatical.

に can be used when 1) the verb is a motion verb such as 行く and 歩く, or when 2) the verb is an existence verb such as いる or ある. When you "do something" somewhere, you need to use で to mark the location. See: [Particles: に vs. で](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60/5010)

(If you've already learned the [`～に + motion verb` construction](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%97%E3%81%AB%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F-ni-iku-meaning/)) You can say 学校に勉強しに行きます ("I go to school to study").

Comment: 2) the verb is an existence verb such as いる or ある. Wanted to add that 住む (to live in) also counts as one of the "existence" verbs and uses に

Comment: I see! Thank you so much. So に can only be used with a select number of verbs while で is preferred when most actions are taking place.